# Proof about binary expansions

Tags: information-theory, binary

I recently came across this argument and I'm not completely sure I understand why it's true.

Say we have two numbers $F_j, F_i \in [0,1]$ such that $F_j \geq F_i + 2^{-l_i}$, where $l_i = \left\lceil \log_2{\frac{1}{p_i}}\right\rceil$, $p_i \in [0,1]$. The argument is that the binary expansion of $F_j$ will differ from the binary expansion of $F_i$ at least once in the first $l_i$ places.

This holds for the examples I've tried but I don't know how you'd go about proving it.

Comment: Hint: their difference is greater than $2^{-l_i}$

Comment: The bit about $l_i = \left\lceil \log_2{\frac{1}{p_i}}\right\rceil$ seems irrelevant except to indicate that $l_i$ is a positive integer. What you want to show may be: Suppose $x,y\in[0,1]$ and $y\ge x+2^{-\ell}$ for some nonnegative integer $\ell$. Show that the binary expansions of $x$ and $y$ differ in at least one of the first $\ell$ places.

Comment: The  binary expansion of a number of the type $2^{-l}$ is 0.0...01 with a 1 in the $l$th bit. So if I add $2^{-l}$ to $x$ it will change the $l$th bit of $x$ if that bit is $0$, and the $l$th bit of $x$ and others to its left if it is $1$. Is that correct?

Comment: You can look at it backwards. Suppose the two numbers _coincide_ in their binary expansions in the first $k$ places. Show that then their difference is at most $2^{-k}$.